# When item is clicked on a stacked bar chart, how do I grey out other bar/stack items?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts with a stacked bar chart. Each part of a bar is clickable and fires a function to filter data in a table.

The standard highcharts `hover` functionality greys out data not in the current series.

I am looking to grey out all other data on the chart except for the stack area on the bar I have clicked.

The illustration below is what I am hoping to achieve. The first image shows all the bars.
The second image shows me having clicked the middle section of the top bar. I need all the other stacks/bars greyed out (disabled).

Ideally a second click would re-enable everything.

(please ignore the hover tooltip on image 2)

[image: Image before click]

[image]

I am currently able to detect and return the current clicked stack item using:

```
series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function () {
                console.log('Series Name : ' + this.name + ', Stack Name: ' + this.series.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case it would return `Series Name : Estimate, Stack Name: Projects In Progress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the finished solution (modified from the standard Highcharts stacked bar chart example).

It allows you to click anywhere on the stacked bar and keep that data point with an opacity of 1 whilst dropping the opacity of all other series/points to 0.3.

Clicking the point a second time will return all points to opacity 1.

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tvg6d5a0/1/

```
var storedId = null;
var chart1 =Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'UEFA CL top scorers by season'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2020/21', '2019/20', '2018/19', '2017/18', '2016/17']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Goals'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#ffffff'
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                inactive: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        var i;
                        var j;
                        //set the opacity back to 1
                        for (i = 0; i < chart1.series.length; i++) {
                            for (j = 0; j < chart1.series[i].data.length; j++) {
                            console.log("here");
                                chart1.series[i].data[j].graphic.attr({opacity: 1});
                                }
                        }
                        if (this.id == storedId) {
                            //code to un-filter external table goes here
                            storedId = null;
                        }
                        else{
                            for (i = 0; i < chart1.series.length; i++) {
                                for (j = 0; j < chart1.series[i].data.length; j++) {
                                    if(j !== this.index || i !== this.series.index) {
                                        chart1.series[i].data[j].graphic.attr({opacity: 0.3});
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //code to filter external table goes here
                            storedId = this.id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        data: [4, 4, 6, 15, 12],
        color: 'red'
    },{
        name: 'Lionel Messi',
        data: [5, 3, 12, 6, 11],
        color: 'green'
    },{
        name: 'Robert Lewandowski',
        data: [5, 15, 8, 5, 8],
        color: 'blue'
    }]
});
```